# Changing Select OPTION based on it's INDEX (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to change the option based on it's index instead of its value.

My current code:
HTML

```
<select name="locations" id="locations">
    <option value="1">loc1</option>
    <option value="2">loc2</option>                 
</select>
<a id="location-1" href="#">Loc 1</a>
<a id="location-2" href="#">Loc 2</a>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#location-1').click(function() {
     alert('first clicked')
                $("#locations").val($("#locations option:first").val());
            });
        $('#location-2').click(function() {
        alert('second clicked')
                $("#locations").val($("#locations option:second").val());
            });
    });
```

How can I change the VAL of #locations through jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/go71tovr/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#location-1').click(function() {
 alert('first clicked')
        $('#location :nth-child(1)').prop('selected', true); // To select via index
        });
    $('#location-2').click(function() {
    alert('second clicked')
        $('#location :nth-child(2)').prop('selected', true); // To select via index
        });
});
```

I updated the code, the above now works!

```
    $('#location :nth-child(2)').prop('selected', true); // To select via index
```

Turns out that is the correct way to word it.